# Deliberately congeal fatty sauce before/on Shabbat so it can be put on the blech in the morning?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, cooking-bishul

According to [SA OH 318:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.318.16) sefardim may deliberately place a dish that has congealed fat onto a blech, even though it will melt and become a liquid. The principle of "en bishul achar bishul" (foods that are already cooked can't be cooked again) applies so this will not break the melacha of cooking on shabbat (even though in general most authorities pasken that this principle doesn't apply to liquids).

I would like to know, is one deliberately allowed to congeal fat *in order that one can have the dish in question on the blech on shabbat, and enjoy its sauce?*

For example, one cooks chicken in a dish, with the sauce and the fats from the chicken. One then puts it in the fridge so that it will congeal for tomorrow, and then in the morning one places this dish on the blech.

Another question which arises (might need to be asked separately?) is does the chicken need to be part of the equation at all? Can one do this simply so one can have a nice sauce on Shabbat?

Comment: How about a fully frozen pot of soup?

Comment: @DoubleAA I've seen quoted in the name of Chacham David that that is prohibited because it would turn into liquid even at room temperature. The reason why congealed fat takes on the status of a "solid" is because it will remain jelly-like even at room temperature, and will only melt if it is heated. If you'd like the exact citation I'm sure I could find it.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on if the fat was congealed before shabbos came in since those authorities are defining this as a davar yavesh based on its current state rather than it's potential?

Comment: It seems from the wording there (many versions employ the word *Pandish* rather than "empanada"  (though they mean the same thing) that it's an issue of Ikar and toefel.  As such it would appear you need the chicken.

Comment: @יהושעק could you explain that reasoning, very interesting

Comment: With pleasure, @RabbiKaiiואף ע"פ שהשומן שבה שנקרש חוזר, "*even though* the congealed fat within will melt

Comment: That is because the Ikar (of the action) is having a warm empanada, we don't concern ourselves with a relatively small amount of fat which will liquefy. Maran S.A. could have used the example of a fatty stew or gravy, but he specifically chose this example. That ואפ ע'פ comes to show you the melting fat is an undesired side effect rather than the main reason for putting the empanada next to the fire

Comment: @יהושעק Amazing thought process! But wouldn't that rule out my example altogether as it would mean one might be obligated to remove the chicken from the sauce before Shabbat because one can easily do that and having the chicken on Shabbat doesn't require the sauce (Pashtida/emapanada does it seems?)

Comment: Thank you, @RabbiKaii! I certainly see what you mean, but, as a practical matter, unless you break shabbat by thoroughly wiping it dry, or rinse it off (which would create a direct violation of heating a liquid rather than an indirect one) there will always be some gravy adhering to the chicken, and once there's some, why not a little more?

Comment: For reference- Pandish,/Empanadas are (usually) crescent shaped dough pockets stuffed with filling, closed up, and either baked or fried, similar to a small calzones.  You can't separate the gravy from the meat filling in the case cited by the SA without opening it up. Interestingly, in today's Israek they are considered a subcategory of bourekas and are always halavi.

Comment: @יהושעק "once there's some, why not a little more" can make a big difference when it comes to hilchos shabbos.